# Python can't import dns package

Tags: python-3.x

I wanna learn coding in python, my first project should display dns setting from domains.

I use python 3.5 on my ubuntu 16.04 server : here the code from my dns.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import dns.resolver
r = dns.resolver.query('padaru.de', 'a')
print (r)
```

the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./dns.py", line 4, in <module>
import dns.resolver
File "/home/users/boogieman/www/bin/dns.py", line 4, in <module>
import dns.resolver
ImportError: No module named 'dns.resolver'; 'dns' is not a package
```

my dns modul are here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dns
```

but I have an `python2.7/dist-packages/`-dir too, and this directory is empty.

It's possible that, my script wanna use the module from the python2.7 dir?

can't find other issues there `:/` can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: It's importing from the file "/home/users/boogieman/www/bin/dns.py". Which I think is your file. Rename it and your issue should be solved.

Comment: ... youre right thx (y)